How can I apply validation and external api authentication in Auth.js (next-auth v5) in NextJS App router and server actions?
I am suffering when trying to apply zod validations and external api auth call, I want to handle all errors and validations and retrun error to the form component to show the errors.
That's how I am reaching it right now, the down side is that I can't redirect to the origin e.g. when user navigate to dashboard when logging in he will be redirected to the home page.
And ofcourse now it is bad practice I am catching redirect error when the user logs in successfully.
// auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { signInSchema } from "./lib/zod";
import api from "./lib/axios";
import { User } from "./lib/types";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Google,
    CredentialsProvider({
      credentials: {
        username: {},
        password: {},
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const fields = signInSchema.parse(credentials);
        const response = await api.post<User>("/auth/login", fields);
        response.data.id = response.data.id.toString();

        return response.data;
      },
    }),
  ],
});

// action.ts
"use server";

import { AxiosError } from "axios";
import { ZodError } from "zod";
import { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import { signIn as signInNextAuth } from "@/auth";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { isRedirectError } from "next/dist/client/components/redirect";

export async function signIn(prevState: any, formData: FormData) {
  try {
    console.log("Signing in...");
    await signInNextAuth("credentials", formData);
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error instanceof AuthError) {
      const err = error.cause?.err;

      if (err instanceof ZodError) {
        const fieldErrors: Record<string, string> = {};
        err.errors.forEach((err) => {
          if (err.path) {
            fieldErrors[err.path[0]] = err.message;
          }
        });
        return { errors: fieldErrors };
      }

      if (err instanceof AxiosError) {
        return { error: err.response?.data.message };
      }
    }

    if (isRedirectError(error)) {
      redirect("/");
    }

    return { error: "Internal server error" };
  }
}

action.ts
auth.ts
